# SwiftyJson errors in swift 1.2

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

SwiftyJson seems to break in swift 1.2, majority of errors are as! not as, however there are some more tricky ones

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Has any found a resolution to this, there was mention of an xcode6.3 branch but i think this is now dead

Really stuggling with Json parsing now

Comment: Wasn't sure if posting would be appropriate, as it's the swiftyjson file. If you drag and drag into an xcode project, it shows 50+ errors. Seems a common issue with new swift upgrade, was just wandering if someone had fixed

Comment: I have no problems with SwiftyJSON and Swift 1.2. Maybe you're using an old version of SwiftyJSON, you should check this. They currently have two branches, one for Swift 1.2 (master), and one for Swift 2 named "Xcode7".

Comment: I also have used SwiftyJSON and Swift 1.2, no problem at all. I am using Cocoa Pods dependency manager to manage all my dependencies and in that i have been using 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2' . Try this it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cocoa Pods as above comment suggests works